# weird jquery symptom

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slider

I'm using jquery to animate the nav menu, and I'm also using a jquery slider on the website (linked below).  If you rollover the first li on the nav menu while the slider is transitioning, it does a really weird jiggle effect on the logo.  It only happens while the slider is transitioning.  Could it be a problem with both scripts executing at the same time?  I'm new to jquery/javascript, so forgive me if this is a stupid question.  Any ideas on how to fix it?

[here's the site.](http://s423839726.onlinehome.us/franklinvineyard/index.php)

thanks!

Comment: Can't see the effect here (Opera 12.11 under Win 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the page animates the menus, it changes the line-heights very subtly. The logo that you have has it's height tied to these subtle changes so you see it ebb and flow a little as those changes are made. The code which ties it to that is in css:

```
.logo
{
 /* ... */
 background-size: 100%;
}
```

Removing this `background-size` style will fix the issue.